# How can I get the total number of child processes called by fork() from this recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion, fork

I've been messing around with this recursive function trying to get the total number of child processes created by `fork()`.  I can't seem to get it right, though.  When I tried to use `WEXITSTATUS()`, the program output became very erratic.  Is there a way to sum the total number of child processes spawned in this function?  Is piping the only way to do that, or is there an easier way?

It gets passed ".", to kick the function off in the current working directory.  It traverses that directory and all subdirectories, forking whenever a subdirectory is found.  `verifyFileType()` just checks if the file found is a CSV.

**Edited function for some more clarity

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int traverse(char* directory)
{
    struct dirent *currentDir;  
    DIR *traverser = opendir(directory);

    if (traverser == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open directory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((currentDir = readdir(traverser)) != NULL)
    {       
        if (currentDir->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            PID = fork();

            if (PID == 0)
            {       
                char pathBuffer[1024];
                snprintf(pathBuffer, sizeof(pathBuffer), "%s/%s", directory, currentDir->d_name);

                traverse(pathBuffer);
                //int childProc = traverse(pathBuffer);
                //return childProc + 1;
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                //do parent stuff?
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            if (verifyFileType(currentDir->d_name) == 0)
            {
                //if directory = '.', only send file name as fopen() arg
                printf("%s%s\n", directory, currentDir->d_name);
            }
        }
    }

    if (PID > 0)
    {
        int status = 0;
        wait(&status);
        //int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        //return returned + 1;
    }
    else if (PID == -1)
    {
        printf("Error waiting on children.  Aborting.\n");
        _exit(0);
    }

    closedir(traverser);
    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* beginningDir = ".";
    rootPID = getpid();

    /*
    int procCount = 0;
    procCount = traverse(beginningDir);
    printf("Proc Count: %d\n", procCount);
    */

    traverse(beginningDir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, does not answer the question, but why do you need to fork for all files? you seem to do it the hard way IMHO (and end up with far to many jobs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only achieve that using an external entity, as forked processes have nothing in common (except parents).
Let's use a file. We can get a file using `tmpfile()`. We would need some locking, using `flock(fileno(FILE *), ...)`. Each child would write a single byte into the temp file. After all childs are run, I can get the size of the file - thus I will get the number of childs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef FILE cnt_t;

/**
 * Create interprocess counter.
 * Should be created once (and only once) by the parent process.
 */
cnt_t *cnt_new(void)
{
    return tmpfile();
}

/**
 * Remove interprocess counter.
 * Should be called by all childs and parent
 */
void cnt_delete(cnt_t *t)
{
    fclose(t);
}

void _cnt_lock(cnt_t *t)
{
    for (int ret; (ret = flock(fileno(t), LOCK_EX)) != 0;) {
        assert(ret == EWOULDBLOCK);
    }
}

void _cnt_unlock(cnt_t *t)
{
    if (flock(fileno(t), LOCK_UN) != 0) {
        assert(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Increments counter by 1.
 */
void cnt_inc(cnt_t *t) {
    assert(t != NULL);
    _cnt_lock(t);

    if (fwrite((char[1]){'X'}, sizeof(char), 1, t) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }

    if (fflush(t) != 0) {
        assert(0);
    }

    _cnt_unlock(t);
}

void cnt_println(cnt_t *t)
{
    _cnt_lock(t);

    if (fseek(t, 0L, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }

    char buf[124];
    size_t cnt = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 124, t);
    printf("cnt(%p) = %ld  '%.*s'\n", cnt, (void*)t, cnt, buf);

    _cnt_unlock(t);
}

/**
 * Get's counter value.
 */
long cnt_getCount(cnt_t *t)
{
    assert(t != NULL);

    _cnt_lock(t);

    if (fseek(t, 0L, SEEK_END) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }

    const long sz = ftell(t);
    if (sz < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }

    _cnt_unlock(t);

    return sz;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

int main()
{
    srand(0);

    cnt_t *cntobj = cnt_new();

    bool child = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        const int ret = fork();
        switch (ret) {
        case 0:
            cnt_inc(cntobj);
            child = true;
            break;
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "fork error!\n");
            exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%d -> %d\n", getpid(), ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) != -1) continue;

    if (child) {
        cnt_delete(cntobj);
        exit(0);
    }

    const long cnt = cnt_getCount(cntobj);
    cnt_delete(cntobj);

    fprintf(stderr, "childs %ld\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I went too much on obfuscucation (`typedef FILE cnt_t` looks strange), but the code works and returns the correct number 31. Live version available at [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Ksl).

And here's a solution just by using pipes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    int p[2];
} cnt_t;

/**
 * Create interprocess counter.
 * Should be created once (and only once) by the parent process.
 */
cnt_t *cnt_new(void)
{
    cnt_t *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    assert(t != NULL);
    if (pipe(t->p) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }
    if (fcntl(t->p[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }
    return t;
}

/**
 * Remove interprocess counter.
 * Should be called by all childs and parent
 */
void cnt_delete(cnt_t *t)
{
    close(t->p[0]);
    close(t->p[1]);
    t->p[0] = 0;
    t->p[1] = 0;
    free(t);
}

/**
 * Increments counter by 1.
 */
void cnt_inc(cnt_t *t) 
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    if (write(t->p[1], (char[1]){'X'}, 1 * sizeof(char)) < 0) {
        assert(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Get's counter value.
 */
long cnt_getCount(cnt_t *t)
{
    assert(t != NULL);

    char c;
    long cnt = 0;
    ssize_t tmp;
    errno = 0;
    while ((tmp = read(t->p[0], &c, 1)) == 1) {
        ++cnt;
    }
    if (tmp < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
        assert(0);
    }

    const long ret = cnt;

    while (cnt--) {
        if (write(t->p[1], (char[1]){'X'}, 1) < 0) {
            assert(0);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

int main()
{
    srand(0);

    cnt_t *cntobj = cnt_new();

    bool child = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        const int ret = fork();
        switch (ret) {
        case 0:
            cnt_inc(cntobj);
            child = true;
            break;
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "fork error!\n");
            exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%d -> %d\n", getpid(), ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) != -1) continue;

    if (child) {
        cnt_delete(cntobj);
        exit(0);
    }

    const long cnt = cnt_getCount(cntobj);
    cnt_delete(cntobj);

    fprintf(stderr, "childs %ld\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Works as good and probably is way faster. Live version still at [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Kst).

These examples use a stupid error handling using `assert`  and they serve just only to show the method and that the method works.

Probably we could also create a solution using posix shemaphores and some interprocess communication, some `shmget` and `semop` and for example queuing sempahore count.

Answer (score 0):

You could try that,
this is really close to what you did, but I just count the number of child I spawn and then wait for them.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int traverse(char* directory) {
    struct dirent *currentDir;
    DIR *traverser = opendir(directory);

    if (traverser == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open directory.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    size_t nb_child = 0;
    while ((currentDir = readdir(traverser)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(currentDir->d_name, ".") == 0
            || strcmp(currentDir->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue; // ignore . and ..

        // if subdirectory => fork to explore
        if (currentDir->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            pid_t PID = fork();

            if (PID == 0) {
                char pathBuffer[1024];
                snprintf(pathBuffer, sizeof(pathBuffer), "%s/%s",
                         directory, currentDir->d_name);

                return traverse(pathBuffer);
            } else {
                nb_child++; // keep track of the nomber of children
            }
        } else { // non directory "file"
                // Do you verify here
                printf("%s%s\n", directory, currentDir->d_name);
        }
    }

    // loop until we waited for all children
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_child; i++)
        wait(NULL);

    closedir(traverser);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    return traverse(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but it seems like your solution is not accounting for processes spawned in the children.  In other words, if I have a subdirectory in a subdirectory, those are not getting accounted for.

Comment: they are accounted by children themselves; each level waits for the sublevel it created (if I did my job correctly)

Comment: Actually, now that I look more closely, it doesn't even account for higher-level ones.  Where is the sum being stored in your example?  I could add a count in the `for` loop with `wait(NULL)`, but that would still only keep track of the parent-most ones, wouldn't it?  There is no process-to-process communication.

Comment: ok, time to get it clear, what are you trying to achieve? the code I gave you actually browse directories even if it does not give the total count. On the other hand, if you need a single variable to hold this, why do you use fork and not a thread?

Answer (score 0):

You spawn a number of children in each process corresponding to the number of sub directories but you do not wait for all of them.

You only wait for the last child. 
You need to store all the PIDs in an array an wait on them in a loop. Then sum all the `WEXITSTATUS` from then and return that value (after adding one for your own).